# How to Listing only items according to a past variable, Like a global variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Good Morning Ionics!

I want to show a list only with products from a single selected vendor.

In my StateProvider I send the selected data, which should be the filter:

```
.state("nhaac.ofertas_restaurante", {
        url: "/ofertas_restaurante/:cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor",
```

And in the view that I want to present data only of the "cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor" selected I put:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass track by $index" ng-if="cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor === item.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}" >
```

But it does not list anything. It goes blank. Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you properly grabbed your url params in the controller with $stateParams and applied to $scope? If not I can add an answer to show you...

Comment: No, I not grabbed the url params in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject $stateParams in the controller and grab the params you want like so:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "$stateParams", function($scope,$stateParams){
      $scope.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor = $stateParams.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor;   
    }
]);
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Thanks, Great solution!